# How to print a java object inside the thymeleaf template?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I need to show the `model` data of the `resultset` object in a price.html which consist with thymeleaf. What is the way of accessing sub elements of resultset object. Is there any way to print the whole object . just like toString(). This is my `Controller` class in spring-boot

```
@PostMapping("/price")
public ModelAndView pricePost(@Valid @ModelAttribute("priceSearch") PriceSearch priceSearch, 
        BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {
    modelAndView.addObject("resultSet", resultSet);
    modelAndView.setViewName("price");
    return modelAndView;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There's no generic way in java to "toString" any random object out of the box if that is what you are looking for. You'll be left to [iterating through](http://www.baeldung.com/thymeleaf-iteration) the items of resultSet and printing it's properties directly.

If you need just *any* textual representation of your object, you could marshal it to JSON in oder to have a look at it.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to access the sub elements of the resultset object using thymeleaf, you would need to do something like this.

```
<th:block th:each="iterator : ${resultSet}">
     <p th:text=${iterator.name}></p>
</th:block>
```

**Note:** I am assuming that resultset is a collection of objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the toString() method of the object-class. Feel free to iterate over nested sub-elements and add their toString()-response to the returned value, e.g.:

```
@Override
public String toString()
{
  String result = /* other properties from the class */ 
  result += "[";
  for (SubElementClass o in this.subElements)
  {
     result += String.Format("(%s)", o.toString());
  }
  result += "]";
  return result;
}
```

It make sense to override to toString() method in the SubElementClass, too.

Another option is not to override the toString method but add a dump() method to a extended class of your original class, which you can called in the template.